# Been trying to install OpenVpn and Mullvad. followed many sets of instructions

Tags: vpn

Can I reverse all commands from the past 8 hrs since original command? I am afraid I may have made some mistakes. I think I may have halfway followed too many sets of instructions... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No you can't, the only way you could do this is to go over your terminal history (kb up arrow) and then look for ways to undo commands, but this will require you to understand every single command you ran.

Some advice for you, try to avoid entering commands you don't understand, need some enlightenment use [the manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/) to understand better, copy pasting loads of commands will inevitably cause a lot of issues, asking the meaning of commands and arguments would be on topic here, so ask, if you are not sure.

If you must run commands you don't understand, [then back up the system first](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem), so if you cause an issue you can just roll back.

Without knowing all the commands you entered and the context with which you entered them, there is no way anyone can help you, but, regardless, you say eight hours worth of commands, there is no way that can be undone here.

If it bothers you then, reinstall seems the best way to go.

Don't be disshartened by breaking your system, trial and error is the best way too learn, just back up first.